# How to show user's id table along with another?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jsp

I'm making a forum and now I've this table. Please take a look at here:

This table is for users:

```
create table if not exists login_system(
user_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
about_yourself VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
my_website VARCHAR(100000) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
);
```

And this table is for questions:

```
create table if not exists thread_question(
question_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
question_title VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
question VARCHAR(100000) NOT NULL,
question_dateTime VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(question_id)
);
```

I want to show a `user's link` If he/she posts his/her question. It must suppose to provide a link after hover on name of the persons. So that other peoples could see his/her profile information.

I can simply fetch some questions to show into forum using this:

```
<%
try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/forum", "root", "1234");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from thread_question where question_id="+question_id);
            while(rs.next()){

                String first_name=rs.getString("first_name");
                String last_name=rs.getString("last_name");
                String thread_title=rs.getString("question_title");
                String thread_question=rs.getString("question");
                String thread_dateTime=rs.getString("question_dateTime");

...
...
...
%>
```

Now my wish is to show `login_system's table` along with `question's table` you know pretty well that we couldn't create two statements along here. So please help.. I want to get `user_id` from `login_system` table where i could easily show his/her profile by clicking the link. Can you please help me? How to do that?

Comment: Unrelated but: please do **not** put SQL code into your JSP pages. And do not create a connection inside a JSP page either. Use a proper connection pool from your servlet container and move the data access code to a servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First follow a horse_with_no_name's adviece an do NOT put SQL code into your JSP pages for security reasons.

Also please fix your grammar/spelling as it was really hard to read your question.

Another thing is you are going to want to go read about normalizing database structures http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

I know pretty well that you can make more than one sql statement if you would like to, it's just another connection, but in this case you should not need to (And most cases)

Change your thread_question table to this

```
create table if not exists thread_question(

    question_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    user_id id INT NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    question_title VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    question VARCHAR(100000) NOT NULL,
    question_dateTime VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(question_id)
    );
```

It looks like the SQL you want is something like this?

```
SELECT 
LS.FIRST_NAME,
LS.LAST_NAME,
TQ.question_title,
TQ.question,
TQ.question_dateTime
FROM
login_system as LS
JOIN thread_question as TQ ON
LS.user_id = TQ.user_id
```

Comment: My one friend also told me to put `user_id` into question's table... thanks ..your answer was good thanks :)

Comment: and there is an error above into your queries... But thanks .. i like that idea to put `user_id` into questions table.. :)

Comment: Looking over it quickly saw a case error, but yeah good luck welcome to coding!

Answer (score 1):

There are various issues with your approach. First, as commented, you should not put the connection code directly into the JSP. Second, you should not create the statement by concatenating strings because of the risk of SQL injection. Make sure you understand what that means and use a `PreparedStatement` instead.

To finally answer your question, rather than having first and last name in the `thread_question` table, you should have a foreign key to the id in the `login_system` table and then use a join in your SQL statement. I guess it would not help you a lot if I would paste the verbatim solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Follow  Shifty solution and if you don't want to join the table then there is one more solution i.e
  1. Fire query to you your thread_question and take data.
  2. When you are preparing your page and giving  userLink you have to attach hover event in javascript which take userid as input and fire ajax call to take the user related data and  use this data.